# to_json methods => []

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, backbone.js

I have the following in my controller as a method:

```
@study = Study.find(params[:id])
respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render :json => @study.to_json(:only => [:id, :first_name, :last_name, :title], :methods => [:active_users]) }
end
```

It's responding to a JSON call. `active_users` is a method of `@study` which turns an array of users. The JSON looks like this:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Anterior segment imaging using ultrasound biomicroscopy (UBM) and slit lamp optic coherence tomography (SL-OCT) in patients using alpha-adrenergic blockers. ",
    "active_users": [
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null
    ]
}
```

The JSON is being returned as all nulls for the user. What should I do differently?

Comment: Also, overloading the as_json method is a no go in this. Thanks!

Comment: What about using rabl gem?

Comment: And what does the array look like in ruby?

Comment: Did you double check that the active_users or your data source is indeed returning something and/or you're parsing them correctly?

Comment: Dennis Rongo you are 100% right. The data source was the issue. Thanks everyone :)